# How To Fix The Horizontal Scroll Bar At Mobile

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I'm experiencing a problem with mobile devices I have a white area in the right of my website and a scroll bar also. So far that I have read this issue is creating cause of an element, but I can't find the solution on it. I have checked my CSS rules and my width is all good in every part. Can anyone suggest me anything else so I can fix that issue?I used the developer options and I was deleting elements to see what element is causing the problem but I didn't find something. My repo is : **https://lazospap.github.io/LazPap/** . EDITED : **https://github.com/LazosPap/LazPap** here are the files

Comment: Please post your code? Without it, external links are pretty unhelpful. Thanks!

Comment: I can tell you it's something to do with your floating animated HTML/CSS/JS items.. consider using a `@media` query to scale them down when on mobile or limit their width to not be a **fixed** value  (i.e. 420px) so that it will better scale down on resolution change.

Comment: Another way to test which section it might be is to remove everything from the page, and just add in one section by itself at a time, so there will only ever be one section on the page. And like EGC said, a jsfiddle with the code in it is extremely helpful.

Comment: I have updated my question with the files that you asked. My images has position relative in my CSS rules, and I have put media queries for HTML/CSS/JS items.

Answer (score 0):

Please put this code in your style

```
html,body{overflow-x: hidden;}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem only temporarily since I have read it, also I can't scroll when insert this code.